# I am doing a POC to protect my angular application with help of C#

Tags: c#, angular

I am create a login page in C# (running at port https://localhost:7139/account/login). Now I want to protect an angular application(running at port https://localhost:4200) from un-authorized user. For now I hard coded the login credentials.I tried to protect the angular application by creating a resolver in my angular application.

My C# (login.cshtml) code

```
<div class="container border" style="padding:20px">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.Username"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" asp-for="Credential.Username" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.Username"></div>
        </div><br />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label asp-for="Credential.Password"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="password" asp-for="Credential.Password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Credential.Password"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My C# controller code

```
using Identity.Pages.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Identity.Controller
{
    

    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("account/login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromForm] Credential credential)
        {
            if (credential.Username == "badruddin" && credential.Password == "khan@123" 
            {
                
               
                return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");

            }

            else
            {
                return NotFound("User Not Found");
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My (Angular) services.service.ts code

```
export class serviceService {
  
   check = true;
  constructor() { }

    loginUrl(): any {
      if(this.check == true){
      this.check = false;
      return window.location.href = 'https://localhost:7139/account/login';
      }
    }
}
```

my (Angular) resolver code is here

```
export class ResolveResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

  constructor(private service:MyserviceService){}
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  
    this.service.loginUrl()
    return of(true);
    
  }
}
```

my (Angular) app-routing.ts code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:AppComponent, pathMatch:'full', resolve: {redirection: ResolveResolver} }
];
```

Now when I tried to open angular application it redirects to me at login page(running at  https://localhost:7139/account/login) and when hitting the login button after putting login credentials it redirects me to angular application(running at  https://localhost:4200) for an instance and then automatically redirects me to the login page(https://localhost:7139/account/login)

I want to stay at angular application once I validate the login credentials.
This time I am not using any cookies or JWT token.

I am new In the field of coding.Can any help me how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Please search how to implement resolver, you will get the article to implement it and more details [example](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/angular-resolver)

Comment: I have already used resolver but I am facing as above discussed problem